# DbSet.Find(id) in the BaseRepository hangs and never returned

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a BaseRepository, where I have this function:

```
    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(id);
    }
```

The issue is that the "return DbSet.Find(id)" hangs and never returned. I think that it is because of a deadlock. The framework tries to get the object from the database but nothings happen only the method hangs. The query never reach to the db. How can we track on which object we have problem. I know that we can simply use the where function instead of the find method.

Comment: weird but if `GetById` is the first use of the repository, then his call triggers the building of the context with all associated code. In this case the error may be far away from `Find`.

Comment: I dont think you assumption is correct, you would get some kind of exception in that case.

Comment: Why dont you place a try catch block around DbSet.Find method.